500kV test application
Please help explain or suggest the best solution for generating a variable output of 100-500 kV DC. No particular current is demanded as long as there is good continuous arcing when I reach a certain voltage level. I am conducting material tests to see at what voltage a material in multiple layers lets electrons pass.
The DC should have as little ripple as possible (no square wave.) It has been many years since I worked with low/high voltage applications so I apologize for the possibly bad terminology. Yes, I know to be careful.
I have read about AC/DC rectifiers and Cockcroft-Walton multipliers, and also DC/DC boosters.
If I use a Cockcroft-Walton multiplier, can I start with 220 V AC, or is it better from the perspective of choosing components for the build to start with a lower or higher voltage?
DC/DC boosters seem harder to achieve high voltage with.
I am not sure what way to go. What choice gives the best result and is not too expensive?

What is the goal of the test? Shall the voltage stay the same when the arc ignites? How big is the arc to be? What gas, what pressure?

What's a Cockcroft-Walton bridge? (seeking clarification from the OP). What you appear to be asking for is loosely a "DC/DC booster" so, what specifically do you have difficulty with in the way they find it harder to achieve higher voltages?

The obvious solution would be a step-up transformer, but 500kV imposes some physical restrictions on the minimum size.  Maybe a transformer to get you up to 20kV or so and a Cockcroft -Walton multiplier to get you the rest of the way?  To vary the voltage - use a variac on the primary of the transformer . X-ray machines are usually in the order of 100kV, so some investigation along those lines might provide a solution. Generating 500kV is very specialised, so be prepared to spend some money!

Thank you for your response. The arc is not important. I just need to be able to clearly see that there has been a discharge.

@Kartman Thank you! Do you know if there are any complications finding components for the C-W multiplier depending on where you start; e.g 240 VAC or 20.000 VAC?
